# Rails, trying to create a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few models, student, Diary and Grade and diary entrys

Every student belongs to a grade, every student has a diary for every grade.

When you create a student record, you select grade, I want to be able to create a diary with the student name and grade.

Diary Model

```html
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :grade
end
```

Student model

```html
class Student < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :diaries, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :subjects, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :grades #confusing for me also... should be in one grade at a time?

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :diaries
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subjects

    def subject_list=(subject_string)
        subject_name = subject_string.split(“,”).collect{ |s| s.strip.downcase }.uniq
       new_or_found_subjects = subject_names.collect { |name| Subject.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
       self.subjects = new_or_found_skills
    end
       
    def subject_list
       self.subjects.collect do |subject|
       subject.name
       end.join(“,”)
    end
end
```

Model for Grade

```html
class Grade < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subjects
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :diary
end
```

Student show page

```html
 <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">

            <%= simple_form_for :diary, url: new_student_diary_path(@student) do |f| %>

<!-- I want to have a button here that creates a diary for the student, without manually entering any information
the information shoud be student_id, user_id and student.grade_id
 -->
            <%= f.submit "Create Diary", class: "btn btn-primary text-center" %>
            <%end%>
          </div>
```

My controller

```html
  def create
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @diary = @student.diaries.build(diary_params)
    @diary.user = current_user
        respond_to do |format|
          if @diary.save
            format.html { redirect_to @diary, notice: 'Diary was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @diary }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @diary.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

My challenge is both in the models, controllers and views... I can't seem to wrap my head around this.... I would really appreciate a step by step answer so that I can learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to scenerio

1 student has 1 diary

1 diary has 1 grade

So,

```
s = Student.new
g = Grade.new
@d = Diary.new(s.id, g.id)
```

1 student has many grades